# Using SB Admin2 Bootstrap template and side-menu don't collapse (menu created from xml/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load a menu from a XML file with JQuery, using SBAdmin2 side-menu (metismenu). But my submenus don't collapse. I click on it and i have no effect. 
When i write HTML directly, whithout loading via xml / jquery it's work and collapse ok, like sbadmin2 demo (https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html). 
I don't want to write menu in HTML directly, so i load it from XML but it's jquery events don't work :(  What´s wrong in my code ?

XML (My Menu)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <MenuRoot>
      <Menu id="home" text="Home" url="home.aspx" acaoSisSeg=""></Menu>
      <Menu id="escola" text="Escolas" url="/View/Escolas/Index.aspx" acaoSisSeg="" icone="fa-institution">
        <SubMenu id="escolaIndex" text="Cadastro de Escolas" url="/View/Escolas/Index.aspx" acaoSisSeg=""></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu id="grau" text="Grau" url="" acaoSisSeg=""></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu id="turmas" text="Turmas" url="" acaoSisSeg=""></SubMenu>
      </Menu>
     <Menu id="professor" text="Professores" url="" acaoSisSeg="" icone="fa-graduation-cap">
        <SubMenu id="professorIndex" text="Cadastro de Professor" url="" acaoSisSeg=""></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu id="professorRemocao" text="Remoção de Professores" url="" acaoSisSeg="">
           <SubSubMenu id="professorRemocaoEfetuar" text="Efetuar Remoção" url="" acaoSisSeg=""></SubSubMenu>
           <SubSubMenu id="professorRemocaoIncluirVagas" text="Incluir Vagas" url="" acaoSisSeg=""></SubSubMenu>
          <SubSubMenu id="professorRemocaoSelecionarOpcao" text="Selecionar Opções" url="" acaoSisSeg=""></SubSubMenu>      
        </SubMenu>
     </Menu>
     <Menu id="aluno" text="Alunos" url="" acaoSisSeg="" icone="fa-group">
        <SubMenu id="alunoIndex" text="Cadastro de Alunos" url="" acaoSisSeg=""></SubMenu>
     </Menu>
   </MenuRoot>
```

HTML of sidebar menu (Using Bootstrap SBAdmin2 template):

```
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
       <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">                
         <div id="menu_wrapper"></div>                
         </div>                                     
       </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery :

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {        
       montaMenu();        
    }); 

    function montaMenu(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/View/menu.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){        
        var html= "<ul class='nav in' id='side-menu'>";
        $(xml).find("Menu").each(function(){                
            html += "<li><a href='#'><i class='fa " + $(this).attr("icone") + " fa-fw'></i> "+$(this).attr("text")+"<span class='fa arrow'></span></a>";

            if($(this).children().length)
            {       
                html += "<ul class='nav nav-second-level'>";

                $(this).children().each(function(){
                     if($(this).children().length) {
                        html+="<li><a href="+$(this).attr("url")+">"+$(this).attr("text")+"<span class='fa arrow'></span></a></li>";
                        html += "<ul class='nav nav-third-level'>";

                        $(this).children().each(function(){
                            html+="<li><a href="+$(this).attr("url")+">"+$(this).attr("text")+"</a></li>";
                        });                   
                        html+="</ul>";       
                     }     
                     else
                        html+="<li><a href="+$(this).attr("url")+">"+$(this).attr("text")+"</a></li>";
                });                    

                html+="</ul>";
            }

            html+="</li>";
        });
        html+="</ul>";
        $("#menu_wrapper").empty();
        $("#menu_wrapper").html(html);

    },
     error: function (response) {
        alert("erro");
    }        
});
    };
```